# Remove unwanted column-gap between two columns

Tags: html, css

I have created a menu with column-count 2. However, there's an unwanted column gap between the elements which makes it impossible for me to give them a proper margin. For some reason if the content of a column is bigger than the other, the column gap is dynamically changing the gap. For example:

I have got two menus. The underscores represent the gap

```
-Item test 1____-Item test 2
-Item test 3____-Item test 4
-Item test 5____-Item test 6
```

When the item names are shorter, the gap is shorter as well:

```
-Item 1__-Item 2
-Item 3__-Item 4
-Item 5__-Item 6
```

I have a screenshot for my example. These are list items and they have got zero padding and margin. Same for the span tag inside.

[image: Long items]

--

[image: Shorter items, exact same styling:]

Shorter items, exact same styling (screenshot above). Excuse the identation here, StackOverflow is messing it up, I guess?

Styling:

```
ul.parent {
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 0;
}

ul.parent li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: FontG;
}
```

HTML Code would be looking like this. It's being rendered via PHP, but the actual output will be like this:

```
<ul class="parent">
    <li>
        <span>Item 1</span>
    </li>
     <li>
        <span>Item 2</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Long Item 3</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Long Item 4</span>
    </li>       
</ul>
```

What could be causing this weird issue?

Comment: Give us hole html and css please or demo code somewhere

Comment: You probably shouldn't use column-count in a list. This is more of a plain text/paragraph property for displaying columns like in newspapers. For creating 2 menus, you should create 2 lists (make use of 2 separate <ul> tags), styling them should be easier.

Comment: @PierreBurton that wouldn't be implementable, since it's one big object I'm receiving in PHP which is rendering one UL with multiple LI's in it. I can't create a new UL every two items, for example.

Comment: Make sure `ul` has no padding and margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The narrower width is most likely a result of a narrower ul. If you want to maintain a larger width set a width on the l, e.g:

```
ul { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use tables also it will arrange dynamically.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td>Long Item 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item2abcdefghi</td>
    <td>Long Item4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```